# Python: Combine two data series with different length corresponding to date

Tags: python

I have two different Time-Series. They start and end both with the same date, but one of the time series is longer than the other. As I would like to do a regression I need to combine the Time-Series and find the dates which are missing.

How would I do it in an easy way? At the moment I try to use the concatenate function.

Comment: So what's the problem here? You've not stated any problem with your current method. Also if this is `pandas` then state this and add the tag

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To [improve your chances to get constructive answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), you should [show us what you have done](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you try either `join` or `merge` with `left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer`, but you need to post raw input data and code to reproduce your time series and also your desired output

Answer (score 0):

`set` intersection will solve your problem with combining two lists of time series into one list:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime as dt
>>> theSameDates1 = [dt.now().isoformat()]*3
>>> theSameDates1
['2015-09-09T11:33:59.989000', '2015-09-09T11:33:59.989000', '2015-09-09T11:33:59.989000']
>>> theSameDates2 = [x for x in theSameDates1]*2
>>> list(set(theSameDates1)|set(theSameDates2))
['2015-09-09T11:33:59.989000']
```